# How to encode special characters (>,<,%) in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can anyone give me a sample script to encode special characters (>,<,%) in jQuery?

Comment: Define "encode."  What are you trying to do and how/why is it failing?

Answer (score 8):

`escape(string)` is a deprecated function.

You can use `encodeURI(string)` for URL-safe strings and `encodeURIComponent(string)` to escape other characters as well: , / ? : @ & = + $ #

`encodeURI("<>?")` returns `"%3C%3E?"`

`encodeURIComponent("<>?")` returns `"%3C%3E%3F"`

Comment: Deprecated? https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.escape

Comment: @Trevor "Not part of any standard.  Mentioned in a non-normative section of ECMA-262." So, even if deprecated is maybe not the correct word, but @Amarok is right that `encodeURI` and `encodeURIcomponent` should be used inside. These functions have appeared later than `escape` and superseded its functionality, so... it is basically deprecated.

Comment: The fact that other functions appeared later doesn't make the previous ones deprecated (unless the standard says so, which plainly it doesn't in this case...) `escape` works as expected. The rest is only a question of personal preference, and definitely not normative.

Comment: I will admit that I had not looked up the details regarding this function in the ECMA standard... I use the IntelliJ IDEA Java/JSP IDE and I was just believing what it showed me: http://i.imgur.com/xEnXU.png

Comment: Well, InteliJ fibbed.  Just because it's not part of a standard, doesn't mean it's "basically deprecated".

Answer (score 0):

```
escape("how to encode special characters(>,<,%) in jQuery")

"how%20to%20encode%20special%20characters%28%3E%2C%3C%2C%25%29%20in%20jQuery"
```